# QM explanation why hot oil explodes when water pours on it

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, molecular-dynamics

I have read this question:

[Why does hot oil explode when pouring water on it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21864/)

It explains in a classical way clearly, that the boiling point of oil is hotter then water, and water changes to steam very fast and explodes the oil.

> Oil heats up faster than water because it has a lower specific heat capacity. As it reaches past boiling point of water as the water is denser than oil so its at the bottom. Then it turns into steam and the steam expands splashing the oil everywhere.
>   As for dropping water into already being hot oil its pretty much the same. Its interface determines the rate of heat flow.

Now I understand that. My question is QM, what happens according to QM, exactly how do the oil molecules explode? How does the water molecule turn to steam molecules so fast and why do these water/steam molecules cause the oil molecules to explode? How does a molecule of oil even explode at the QM level?

I do understand that when there is a classical explanation, then we should not bother with QM, though, I believe this is the case when we could look into the deeper QM level.

Question:

1. what is the QM explanation, how do the water/steam molecules expand and transfer their energy to the oil molecule, and how does an oil molecule at the QM level explode?

Comment: What is the world do you think that asking for a QM framing is going to add to the existing treatment? The processes at work happen at scale and incoherently.

Comment: The oil molecules don't explode. The material just spatters everywhere. Nothing happens to the molecules other than an increase of kinetic energy (increased in temperature for the bulk material).

Comment: "I do understand that this question is not useful and irrelevant, but I still want you to answer it"? Is this something you consider constructive? If so, why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as the question itself explains, the premises are faulty.

Comment: @electronpusher thank you, are you saying that the molecules stay intact all the way? is it just kinetic energy from the vibrational energies of the water/steam that moves the oil?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I would like to know if the molecules fall apart or if it is just the vibrational energies of the water/steam molecules that transforms into the kinetic energy of the oil molecules?

Comment: If the molecules "fall apart", you don't have oil and water any more. You would have the products of some chemical reaction that took place. But oil doesn't react with water at the sort of temperatures and pressures involved in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the water, 1 litre of water converts to approx 1700 litres of steam, so throw droplets of water onto hot oil and the water sinks & turns to steam very quickly blowing hot oil around...

Comment: thank you, are you saying that the hot oil molecules vibrational energies (heat) pushes the oil molecules away, giving them kinetic energy?

Comment: so it is the volume change of the molecules' and the material?